# Is it possible to be overfitted with low training accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm working with document classification problem and I tried to apply basic RNN/LSTM model.

I made multi-layered LSTM model and trained with 15 epochs but I got about 53% training acc. and 41% test acc.. When I trained with larger epochs, training acc. increased and test acc. decreased to about 33%.
I knew if test acc. is lower than training acc., it can be overfitting. And the cause of the overfitting is that, the model trained even the noise of the train dataset. But I think if overfitting occurred, training acc. has to be quite high (80-90%) and test acc. is quite lower than that since overfitting means the model was literally 'overfitted' to train dataset.

Now I'm wonder why I got 10%-lower accuracy when I trained with 15 epochs and got just 53% of training acc.. Is it overfitting? Can overfitting occur when I got quite low training acc.?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Re title: sure, why not?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thx for your comment! As I wrote on the body, I thought overfitting literally 'overly trained' the train dataset (even noise). So I thought the result of overfitting are much higher train acc and lower test acc. Can you help me to fix my wrong thought? Thanks!!

Comment: Generally speaking (very generally), training set accuracy tends to keep increasing because that's what the optimizer is trying to do. Unfortunately, we've seen that past a certain point, using the optimizer to further increase training accuracy can cause your model to perform worse in the "real world". To determine when this point is, we keep checking a validation set; when the validation set starts performing worse and worse, we realize that our optimizer is only making real-world model performance worse. If your model isn't a good model (or your optimizer), you'll hit this point early.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I really appreciate it. I will check with valid set. But if valid acc is also bad, alternatives are: change model or change optimizer, right? Is there any other alternatives? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This page lists a couple of typical things to check: https://machinelearningmastery.com/improve-deep-learning-performance/. One easy thing to try as well is to reduce your learning rate by a factor of 10 or 100.

Comment: This page looks really helpful for me!! I will check and try some methods on it. Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Low training accuracy is an indicator that your model doesn't have enough capacity to fit the training data (assuming the dataset is consistent). This is usually called the underfitting regime. But even then, it is not necessarily guaranteed that validation/test accuracy will be identical due to the difference in data distribution and noise. This is especially true if the dataset is small. In your case, you can increase model capacity (by adding more layers, increasing number of neurons etc.) so that it can achieve high accuracy on training data. After that you can add different regularization techniques (dropout, weight decay etc.) to reduce overfitting.